# At the time I test logout The result of executing req.isAuthenticated() is always false.(node js passport login problem)

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I am implementing login using passport. and I have a question about a tricky login problem

login router is this

```
router.post('/login', isNotLoggedIn ,(req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return next(err);
        }
        if (info) {
            return res.status(401).send(info.reason);
        }
        return req.login(user, async (loginErr) => {
            if (loginErr) {
                console.error(loginErr);
                return next(loginErr);
            }
            // console.log("user : ", user);

            console.log("login check : ", req.isAuthenticated());

            const fullUserWithoutPassword = await User.findOne({
                where: { id: user.id },
                attributes: {
                    exclude: ['password']
                },
                include: [{
                    model: Post,
                    attributes: ['id'],
                }, {
                    model: User,
                    as: 'Followings',
                    attributes: ['id'],
                }, {
                    model: User,
                    as: 'Followers',
                    attributes: ['id'],
                }]
            })
            // console.log("fullUserWithoutPassword : ", fullUserWithoutPassword);
            return res.status(200).json(fullUserWithoutPassword);
        });
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

and result of below code is true

```
            console.log("login check : ", req.isAuthenticated());
```

Whenever I try to log out, if I check whether I am currently logged in and req.user is set, the result is as follows.

```
req.isAuthenticated() => false. 
console.log("logout check :::::::::::::", req.user); => undefined
```

logout router

```
router.post('/logout',  (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("login check :::::::::::::", req.isAuthenticated());
    console.log("logout check :::::::::::::", req.user);

    req.logout();
    req.session.destroy();
    res.send('ok')
})
```

I am looking for the cause of this problem.
Maybe back/app.js is in the wrong order?
or pass port code is wrong?
Or is it something else?

Thanks for your review

back\app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const postRouter = require('./routes/post');
const userRouter = require('./routes/user');
const cors = require('cors');
const session = require('express-session');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const passport = require('passport');
const passportConfig = require('./passport');


const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();

const app = express();
const db = require('./models');

db.sequelize.sync()
    .then(() => {
        console.log("db connection success !!");
    })
    .catch("error : ", console.error)
passportConfig();


app.use(cors({
    origin: '*',
    credentials: true,
}));

    
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser(process.env.COOKIE_SECRET));

app.use(session({
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: { maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 },
    secret: process.env.COOKIE_SECRET,
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("hello express");
});

app.use('/post', postRouter);
app.use('/user', userRouter);

app.listen(3065, () => {
    console.log("Ecpress Server is Excuting");
});
```

passport/index.js

```
const { User } = require('../models');
const passport = require('passport');
const local = require('./local');


module.exports = () => {
    passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
        done(null, user.id);  
    });
    passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
        try {
            const user = await User.findOne({ where: { id }});            console.log("user : ", user);
            done(null, user);
        } catch (error) {
            done(error);
        }
    });
    local();
}
```

passport/local.js

```
const passport = require('passport');
const { Strategy: LocalStrategy } = require('passport-local');
const { User } = require('../models');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

module.exports = () => {
    passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'password'
    }, async (email, password, done) => {
        try {
            const user = await User.findOne({
                where: { email }
            });
            if (!user) {
                console.log("email is not exists");
                return done(null, false, { reason: 'email is not exists' });
            }
            const result = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
            if (result) {
                console.log("result :::::::::::::" , result);
                return done(null, user);
            }
            return done(null, false, { reason: 'pass word is wrong' });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            console.error(error);
            return done(error);
        }
    }));
}
```

Comment: github is this : https://github.com/hyunsokstar/prepare

Comment: Ciao, if in the same places you log req.isAuthenticated you try to log `req.session.passport.user !== undefined` what do you receive?

Comment: console.log("session check :::::::::::::", req.user); ==> undefined

Comment: console.log("giovanni check", req.session.passport.user); ==> ?

Comment: I excuted  console.log("giovanni check", req.session.passport.user) but error is occuered  error message :TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined
to Giovanni Esposito

Comment: Ok, last check: console.log(req.isUnauthenticated()); ==> ?

Comment: console.log(req.isUnauthenticated()); ==> ? 
it's true thanks

Comment: No problem. I'm writing my answer to complete your question. If you want, mark it as correct answer. Ciao and have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciao, try to modify `/logout` post like that:

```
router.post('/logout',  (req, res, next) => {
   console.log("login check :::::::::::::", req.isUnauthenticated());

   req.logout();
   req.session.destroy();
   res.send('ok')
})
```

req.isUnauthenticated() is equal to true so that means that after you logout the request is always unauthenticated.

Comment: i excuted like this and result is true

Comment: So this means that at the time you logging out, the req is always unauthenticated. That's the reason why req.isAuthenticated returns false.